# How could I print a PDF at 98.5 scale on Windows 10?

Tags: pdf, printing, printer

I have a PDF file that I need to print such that it precisely matches another printout. After running some calculations based on measuring lines, I have found that I need to print a file at 98.5% scale.

When I try to print the file, there is a text box that allows the user to input a scale value. As part of trying to resolve the issue I have already created a 98% scale printout. When I tried entering 98.5%, the 0.5% is truncated, and a 98% printout results. The following creates a 98% scale printout:

[image]

Is there a way to print with a more precise scale on Windows 10?

Comment: Can you scan the other printout to PDF and match them that way?

Comment: What PDF application are you using?  Can you use a different PDF application?  This likely is a limitation of the PDF application itself and a different application might allow the value you want.  However, the value might be allowed, but it's entirely possible it will silently be ignored.

Comment: @John While that is a great suggestion, the reason I'm going through this is because when I print on my iPad, one of the colors is wrong but the scale is correct (this would be the source printout). When I print on PC, all the colors are correct, but the scale is wrong. A scan at correct scale would unfortunately copy the wrong colors.

Comment: @Ramhound I am opening the PDF on Microsoft Edge and printing from there.

Comment: If it needs to precisely match another printout, simply print both documents at 100%.

Comment: @Gantendo this is a good point. The source printout is printed from an iPad, specifically Cricut Design Space. The prompt for printing that that application provides has no scaling options. After trying numerous print scales, I have determined that the application creates a printout that is 98.5% scale.

Comment: @user2738698 Can you download Cricut Design Space on your pc and print the file from there?

Comment: @Gantendo Yes, I have done that and when I try to print the file from Cricut Design Space on PC, it prints at around 99% scale.

Comment: Windows does NOT let you print pdf files at a non-whole number scale, so you are going to have to go to another program.  Export you drawing to adobe and print from Adobe Reader.

Comment: @user2738698: Can you show top half of print options/dialog box? which printer you have chose? Do you have the PDF in your computer or it is on a limited access devise or web?